# Error importing anydbm python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7

I get the following error when trying to import anydbm in python 2.7.6. Does anyone know whats going wrong? Appreciate your help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py", line 50, in <module>
_errors.append(_mod.error)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloading the information about available software in Ubuntus Software & Updates GUI fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dbm` it should work. I know in Python3 `anydbm` to `dbm` has been renamed.

```
import dbm
```

Comment: Reloading the information about available software in Ubuntus Software & Updates GUI fixed the problem. Thanks anyway!